# Subroute is/ cannot be displayed

Tags: vue.js

As shown in the following figure, it can only be displayed when // appears，Want to use main as a template to apply sub routes[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ji5VD.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anKvX.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLg4f.png)
How to solve this problem

Comment: Please post your code as a text instead of links to images

Answer (score 0):

In the `children` array, you have to define a named path in order for it to render. In your case it should be something like this:

```
    const routes = [
      path: '/',
      component: () => import('../views/Main.vue'),
      children: [
        {
          path: 'home',
          name: 'home',
          component: () => import('../views/home/Home.vue')
        }
      ]
    ]
```

You're basically creating children routes here which means if the parent route is `'/'`, and the child route is `'home'`, the home component will be displayed on the path `'/home'`. In this route, `'/'` is the parent route and `'home'` is the child component route.